# Is 11th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-11390H Processor (12MB Cache, up to 5.0GHz with ITBM3.0) compatible with LInux Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, dell-inspiron

I'm looking at new Dell laptop with i7-11390H Processor https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/laptops/intel/spd/inspiron-15-5510-laptop/ni155510_sb_h5011ce
[image]

I checked [Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202101-28595) and found out that it has only Dell Inspiron 5510 (**Core i7-11370H**).
Is it possible that **i7-11390H** supports Linux 20.04, but it is not included in the list yet?

Comment: What does your research show, how would we know more than Canonical?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I'll try to ask Dell representatives. I thought maybe there is some period during which new processors are tested on Linux compatibility.  Maybe someone had a similar problem with previous Dell or processor models.

Comment: I note that your top link is for a Ryzen based system, not an Intel based one, I suspect you meant https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-laptop/spd/inspiron-15-5510-laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work absolutely fine, its just that there is no agreement between Dell and Canonical for testing for this specific chipset (and even then, I expect that if they are both Inspiron 5510's they are both covered with the Dell advisory.  These chips are [pretty much identical](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/compare.html?productIds=217183,217182) except for the cache and CPU speeds - almost certainly they come off the same line and are just binned differently, as is common practice with Intel CPU's.

Another take on this - the CPU is almost certainly supported by Linux and thus Ubuntu.  The certification of a device typically looks at the "other" elements of it, like the touchpad, network card and other drivers.  These will be the same on all Dell 5510's and thus will work fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: I asked Dell support today and they told they this computer is compatible with LInux Ubuntu 20.04. It was tested from their side only. I also suggested them to work more closely with Canonical on certification

Comment: @vitalis While I am in the tiny minority who only use Linux on the desktop, I think that expecting Dell to certify very similar systems with canonical is unreasonable due to costs.  For yhe infintessimally small market of "people who must have Canonical Certified" desktops, why should they not pay slightly extra - less then the cost of a retail Windows license I expect - for the better model, or why should I need to pay more for the i5 system both Dell and myself know will work fine?

Comment: Thank you, I'll take it into the account.